# Can the polyfill.ts file be deleted?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, polyfills

I have this **polyfill.ts** file in my app that have these import statements:

```
import 'zone.js/dist/zone'; 
import 'core.js';
import 'core-js/modules/es6.map';
import 'regenerator-runtime/runtime';
import 'core-js/es6/reflect';
```

But upon checking on the console log, it has an Uncaught TypeError in the **polyfill.js** file (**note:** error on **polyfill.js** file, not on the **polyfill.ts** file)

Is there a way to not load these polyfill files? Is it also possible to delete this **polyfill.ts** file even though it is auto-created?

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: @NalinRanjan I am receiving this error in the console --> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When building the project,`polyfill.ts` is used to create `polyfill.js` build artifact which contains all the polyfills required to support a missing functionality in older browsers.

> Is it also possible to delete this polyfill.ts

Try to **avoid deleting this file** because polyfill.ts contains `zone.js` polyfill. Your app may produce errors when running on older browsers. You can however remove the ones not required by your project.

Here is the summary of what these polyfills do:

**import 'zone.js/dist/zone';** : Internally required by angular to create a wrapper around async tasks for change detection & angular renderer to work properly on older browsers.

**import 'core.js';
import 'core-js/es6/reflect';
import 'core-js/modules/es6.map';** : Useful for IE support which misses many of the modern ES6 functionalities. You can remove these if you don't support IE.

**import 'regenerator-runtime/runtime';** : Adds polyfill for generator/yield functions.

Answer (score 7):

Since Angular 15, the polyfill file is not required anymore.

You can pass `zone.js` directly in `angular.json`

```
"polyfills": [
  "zone.js"
]
```

See "CLI Improvements" section in the Angular 15 release [blog post](https://blog.angular.io/angular-v15-is-now-available-df7be7f2f4c8).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to delete the **polyfills.ts** file from my project completely by following Matthieu Riegler's solution and then removing the `"polyfills.ts"` from the `"files"` area of my **"src/tsconfig.*.json"** files.