# Error: Module not found: Error: Package path ./dist/zone is not exported from package

Tags: angular

After upgrading from Angular 16 to Angular 17 I get following error message when I try to run the application with `ng serve` or build it with `ng build`:

> ./src/polyfills.ts:55:0-27 - Error: Module not found: Error: Package path ./dist/zone is not exported from package /Users/<MY_USERNAME>/<MY_ANGULAR_PROJECT>/node_modules/zone.js (see exports field in /Users/<MY_USERNAME>/<MY_ANGULAR_PROJECT>/node_modules/zone.js/package.json)

Answer (score 40):

According to [Can the polyfill.ts file be deleted?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70677379/can-the-polyfill-ts-file-be-deleted) the file `src/polyfill.js` is not needed any longer (since Angular 15).

So to fix above errror simply replace all occurences of `"polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts"` in the file `angular.json` with `"polyfills": ["zone.js"]` and your Angular 17 application will build successfully.

Comment: In case if you have not only "import 'zone.js/dist/zone';" in polyfills.ts you may simply comment out the zone line there and update angular.json by adding zone.js like this "polyfills": ["zone.js", "src/polyfills.ts"]

Comment: I would have expected a migration to handle this in the upgrade, weird. Worth noting, I also had to remove the polyfill file reference from my tsconfig files, or you'll get some other similar errors.

Answer (score 17):

The version `0.14.0` of `zone.js` introduced a breaking change. (cf the [release note](https://github.com/angular/angular/releases/tag/17.0.0-next.5)).

Deep and legacy `dist/` imports like `zone.js/bundles/zone-testing.js` and `zone.js/dist/zone` are no longer allowed. `zone-testing-bundle` and `zone-testing-node-bundle` are also no longer part of the package.

The proper way to import `zone.js` and `zone.js/testing` is:

```
import 'zone.js';
import 'zone.js/testing';
```

Answer (score 13):

In file `src/polyfill.js`, replace

```
import 'zone.js/dist/zone';
```

to

```
import 'zone.js';
import 'zone.js/testing';
```

Comment: If the suggested change to `polyfills.js` (or `polyfills.ts`) doesn't work to resolve the issue, try that update in `src/main.ts`.  That's what solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 2):

When you use the Angular Update Guide website it warns you about this.

[Guide to update your Angular application v16.0 -> v17](https://update.angular.io/?l=2&v=16.0-17.0)

> Change **Zone.js** deep imports like **zone.js/bundles/zone-testing.js** and **zone.js/dist/** zone to **zone.js** and **strong text**

In file **src/polyfills.ts** change this `import 'zone.js/dist/zone'` to this `import 'zone.js';`